# In swift, what does set in parentheses mean?

Tags: swift, class, variables, accessor

Getters and setters are understandable however after following a tutorial from a text, I'm having trouble understanding what the word 'set' in parentheses means when declaring the variable?

```
 private (set) var price:Double{
    get{return priceBackingValue}
    set{priceBackingValue=max(1,newValue)}
}
```

What is the purpose of adding '(set)' in the variable scope and naming convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the access modifier for setting the variable `price` is private, where as the variable can still be accessed (aka. get) as if it was public.

```
class Doge {
  private(set) let name = ""
  func someMethod(newName: String) {
    name = newName //This is okay because are setting the name from within the file
  }
}
```

In a different file (note: private means private to the file not class!):

```
let myDoge = Doge()
print(myDoge.name) //This is okay as we can still access the variable outside of the file
myDoge.name = "foo" //This is NOT okay as we can't set the variable from outside the file
```

**EDIT:** more accurate to mention how private applies to the file not actually the class - as mentioned by @sschale

Comment: So what you're saying is that its been declared as private so it'll be inaccessible by other classes...however by adding '(set)', then the property is accessible to where other classes can only set this property?

Comment: @LaurenceWingo essentially yes, so think about it as just `private` means the setters and getters are both private but `private(set)` means the private access modifier only applies to the `set`.

Comment: Got it!!  Just to be sure.  In your above code, if we changed '(set)' to '(get)' then myDoge.name= "foo" would be allowable and work right?

Comment: @LaurenceWingo well actually theres no such `private(get)` because the setter must have a access modifier less than or equal to the getter. This wouldn't be very helpful if we could change a variable outside of its class but not access it. You can apply an access modifier for the `get` of the variable along with the modifier for `set` like so: `internal private(set) var ...`

Comment: @LaurenceWingo If this answer was helpful and answered your question, could you mark it as the selected answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It basically indicates that the variable `price` is only settable by the class that defines it, i.e. it is a private setter. This is convenient in cases where you want the variable to be **readable** by other classes, but only settable by the class that defined it.

```
class A {

  private (set) var foo = "foo" // variable can be read by other classes in the same scope, but NOT written to(!)

}

let a = A()
a.foo // fine! You can only read this one though!
```

whereas in this example, the variable is not accessible by other classes at all (neither settable nor gettable)

```
class B {

  private var bar = "bar" // other classes have no access to this variable

}

let b = B()
b.bar // you cannot read/write this variable
```

As **sschale** points out in the comments, obviously putting classes into the same files will expose the private members/properties of a class to the others within the same file, so take that into account iff you are putting more than one class into a file.

Comment: You can actually access `private` components of a class if they are within the same `.swift` file though.

Comment: that's very true, going to add that as well. I was primarily aiming at illustrating the point in a real-world use case where classes reside in different files, but again, your point is perfectly valid.